# Difference between int[] a = {1,2,3} and int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3}

Tags: java, arrays

What is the difference between

`int[] a = {1,2,3}`

and

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3} ?
```

Which one is more efficient for creating a simple array?

Comment: There's no difference

Comment: I have improved the question to be more useful. @Reimeus Would you please unmark it as a duplicate.